# Laravel belongsTo & hasMany relationship not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am having this problem since today (Previously given code was working totally fine) that i am unable to get the **title** of **Category** model in blade.

blade.php

```
@foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
    {{ $subcategory->category->title }}
@endforeach
```

Category.php

```
public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }

protected $table = 'sub_categories';
```

SubCategory.php

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

Error i get is

```
"Trying to get property 'title' of non-object
```

response i receive as **json**

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Paint",
    "category_id": "1",
    "active": "1"
  }
}
```

response with eager loading

```
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Paint",
    "category_id": "1",
    "active": "1",
    "created_at": "2019-01-24 06:48:39.697",
    "updated_at": "2019-01-24 06:48:39.697",
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Chemical",
      "active": "1",
      "created_at": "2019-01-24 06:48:38.533",
      "updated_at": "2019-01-29 05:41:14.597"
    }
  },
```

**[UPDATED]**
I get the category, when i use {{ $subcategory->category }} only;

```
{"id":1,"title":"Chemical","active":"1","created_at":"2019-01-24 06:48:38.533","updated_at":"2019-01-29 05:41:14.597"}
```

Cleared following;

cache:clear

config:clear

route:clear

composer update

composer dumpautoload

Browser Cache Cleared

Still not working

Help Appreciated

Comment: have you tried using `$subcategory->category['title']` ?

Comment: That did the trick. Why? Can you elaborate. Rest of the relationships working fine, but why this one is not?

Comment: Now, it is not showing title, where as it is coming up in json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this.

```
@foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
    $subcategory = (array) $subcategory;
    ///"Trying to get property 'title' of non-object 
    ///(upper code object data convert into array data)
    {{ $subcategory->category->title }}
@endforeach
```

**OR**

if it is not working, please change your relationship with fields name.

//// Category

```
public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'id', 'cat_id');
}
```

//// SubCategory

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id', 'sub_id');
}
```

Comment: Update Code, if it is json response "{{ $subcategory->category }}", please convert into array using json_decode($subcategory->category)

Answer (score 0):

since category has subcategory and subcategory is the child, let try it this way

```
$category = category::with('subcategory')->get();
foreach($category as $cat){
$title = $cat->category[0]->title;
```

or if this does not work

```
$title = $cat->category->title;
}
```

Comment: did you put it under the foreach statement?

Comment: Yes, it is under foreach loop

Comment: Category hasMany right? then tweak your code like this, $category=category::with('subcategory'), then loop through and get the the value like $category->subcategory[0]->title